# Should we create a canonical for questions asking why HTTP requests work only in a specific scenario?

Tags: discussion, canonical

A very common question I often see takes the form of the following:

> I have made an HTTP request in <Tool A> and it works. But when I try to do the same in <Tool B> and/or <Tool C> and/or <Tool D>, it fails. What am I doing wrong?

[Example.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67586817/70345)

These questions may or may not include code samples, which are mostly irrelevant to the question anyway, because the only correct answer to such a question is "we have no idea, you need to debug the various requests and see how they differ, using a tool like Fiddler".

Theoretically, such questions should thus be closed as "needs details/clarity" or "needs debugging details" since the user would already have the answer if they'd used Fiddler. The problem is that they *don't know how to*, and as such this represents an opportunity for us to teach them how to fish, rather than just closure/deletion.

Therefore I'm proposing a canonical question that essentially covers this scenario, with a canonical answer that basically boils down to "this is where to get Fiddler and here is how to use it". This new canonical can then be used as a dupe-close target for similar questions in future.

I know some members of the community have an issue around canonical dupes, but as far as I can tell this is mostly related to the scenario when such dupes become large and unfocused enough to end up effectively useless. I don't believe that would be the case here, which is why I'm proposing it.

Thoughts?

Comment: These questions are very contextual. There are millions of ways these can fail even for a very specific platform.

Comment: I can see upsides and downsides to this; if these problems truly are extremely contextual, then having a dupe is kind of contradictory; but if the dupe would be a good resource to help readers help themselves, then that still sounds like a win on some level.

Comment: I think my opinion is that this would be better off as a wiki of some sort that lives *on meta*, which we can link users to when relevant. Then we can still close such posts for "needs details or clarity," which *is* the appropriate close reason here in majority of cases.

Comment: You mean something like [How do I monitor all incoming http requests?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4428680/215552)

Comment: Related: [Introducing new user onboarding project](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/364572/266284)

Comment: It's possible that we'd need several canonicals depending on the tools involved ("Why does my request work in Postman but not my Android app in Retrofit?), though I like the idea.  Probably at least some could be combined, like the various Android HTTP libraries.